# Building an Array from an ResultSet?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm pretty new to the whole SQL and Java thing, but here I'm actually really confused.

I have a method which is called by invoking a few array parameters, as following

```
Method(String[], int, int[], int[])
```

I'm doing a ResultSet to check to see if there are any rows available where there is an ID match for the searched item.

```
ResultSet group = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `circulation` WHERE `ItemID` = "+itemID);
```

However, I'm completely stumped here on how to construct the method.

The String[], and int[] parameters are what is stored in the database, while the standard int parameter is the itemID. I have no idea how to go about doing this to call the Method correctly.

Darn, I thought I was doing good, too.

Comment: Since you do not know how many results you will get, a practical way would be storing them first in a dynamic structure (like a  `java.util.List`) before assigning them to a static one (the array).

Comment: "The String[], and int[] parameters are what is stored in the database" So you have two arrays that contain values from different columns per row from the database? You should really create a class that represents whatever your database stores, and have a single collection (probably some kind of List, maybe an ArrayList, rather than an array).

Answer (score 2):

Arguments are normally used to provide information to the method being called. To get information from the method being called, you normally use a return value.

Your method seems to search rows in a database table named `circulation` for a given item ID. The item ID should thus be an argument. The found rows should be a returned value. The signature of the method should thus be:

```
Circulation[] findByItemId(int itemId);
```

Or better, using collections instead of arrays:

```
List<Circulation> findByItemId(int itemId);
```

What is `Circulation`? It's a class that represents what a row of the circulation table contains. So if the table contains an ID, a name and an item ID, this class would look like

```
public class Circulation {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int itemId;

    // constructor, getters, and other useful methods omitted for brevity
}
```

Your `findByItemId()` method will thus create an empty list of Circulation, then iterate over the rows of the result set, construct a `Circulation` instance for each row, and add the instance to the list. And then it will return that list.

Finally, you're using concatenation to build a SQL query taking parameters. This is dangerous. You should use a prepared statement instead. Read [the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) about them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apache commons-dbutils. It is a simple wrapper around JDBC and lets you convert your resultsets into any standard datastructures

Answer (score -1):

You can use function

> rs.getArray()

with columnName or ColumnLabel. 
But this function return objects array and you can cast it to Integer and String.